# JSON http.get return áá flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve a JSON from a URL link. The JSON data consist of both English and Burmese language. However, when I retrieve the data, the app shows a bunch of Burmese words converted into "áá". Any solutions?

---

```
class _GetJsonResultState extends State<GetJsonResult> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var jsonFileName = "assets/resultlist/resultlist.json";

    fetchData() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('https://jsonkeeper.com/b/47QP');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return(response.body);
    }
  }

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
        if (myData == null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              // Loads upon null
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Home(myData: myData);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

[image: What I get from the result]

This is what I'm supposed to get
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your fetchData() function as below

```
fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonkeeper.com/b/47QP',
      headers: {"charset": "utf-8", "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"});
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return (utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, mind explaining a little why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Its a decoding issue. Just to clarify what is happening in background

The Dart http API defines (as mentioned below) two ways of interacting with the response data:

```
body → String
The body of the response as a string. This is converted from bodyBytes using the charset parameter of the Content-Type header field, if available. If it's unavailable or if the encoding name is unknown, latin1 is used by default, as per RFC 2616.

bodyBytes → Uint8List
The bytes comprising the body of this response.
```

More details at https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175#issuecomment-415721621

So in such cases where you know encoding before hand and think its going to mess use request encoding and a decode from byte

```
fetchData() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonkeeper.com/b/47QP',
      headers: {"charset": "utf-8", "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"});
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return (utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  }
}
```

Comment: Clear explanation! Thank you so much.